# Django, forcing reload of css/js, and collectstatic

Tags: css, django, static-files

Let's say that I've done a good bit of update to my css files on my dev machine (with my browser set to ignore the cache, no always seeing updates right away).

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-the-browser-to-reload-cached-css-js-files) and other places, I've seen the approach of adding a version number to the links:

`<link type="text/css" href={% static "/path/mystyles.css?version=2" %} rel="stylesheet">`,

which is fine, but on the dev machine, I get an error in the console, and the file isn't found:

`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/path/mystyles.css%3Fversion%3D2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I've read that perhaps `collectstatic` will fix it on the dev side, but there's an ominous-looking warning:

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /patttthhhhh/static

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?
```

What will happen when I run `collectstatic`? Where will it get files from to overwrite those?

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working easily was changing the format of the version tag:

`<link type="text/css" href="{% static '/path/mystyle.css' %}?version=2" rel="stylesheet">`

instead of:

`<link type="text/css" href={% static "/path/mystyles.css?version=2" %} rel="stylesheet">`

Is fine in dev and production.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way would be to use something like django-compressor ([usage](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#examples)) or the likes to process your CSS into a single file and then bake a hash into the filename or dir. So that way your asset would become `/mystyles.beb23fe.css`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found to do this without having to change the css file every new version was to do it this way using time.time() which will give you a different value every time the page is called. You can do this if your project is somewhat medium or small. I wouldn't do this for a critical project necessarily:

In a file called context_processors.py (I put it in my core app):

```py
import time


def version(request):
    return {"VERSION": str(time.time())}
```

Then configured it in settings.py:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                ...
                "core.context_processors.version",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And then in my template I have this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}?version={{VERSION}}">
```

It seems to work really well in production.